# Trying to install bull-repl on Ubuntu 20.4, getting strange npm error

Tags: node.js, npm, bull.js, bullmq

I am trying to install bull-repl package on my Ubuntu 20.4 system via

```
sudo npm i bull-repl -g
```

But I keep getting following error:

```
> node-jq@1.11.2 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/bull-repl/node_modules/node-jq
> npm run install-binary

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall scandir
npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_logs
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 65534:1000 "/root/.npm"
glob error [Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/root/.npm/_logs'
}
...
```

I tried to clean the npm cache and some other stuff that was mentioned in another post about similar problem. And oc I tried solution from the message :)

Answer (score 0):

you have a permission issue to write into `/root/.npm`. i strongly suggest that you will not run npm as root user but on behalf of another user.

i am sure it will solve your problem.

otherwise, grant the relevant permission on `/root/.npm`

Comment: Yes I also tried running the commands as root but with no success. So whats your suggestion again? Did not get it :)